# How to use start-sleep with value assign in variable using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, time, delay, wait, pause

I would like to use start-sleep in powershell. But I need to assign the value to variable. But seem the value is inconstant if the variable not using [int]. Is it true that if we want to use start-sleep the value supposed to be an int like this [int]$value?

Is this two different?

```
$Value_1 = 9
[int]$Value_2 = 9

Start-Sleep -s $Value_1

Start-Sleep -s $Value_2
```

Comment: Both variables are of the type `int`, one is dynamically typed and the other one is type constrained. Both have the same effect. Even if the variable had a `string` containing only digits, `Start-Sleep` would work fine too.

Comment: why do you consider it `inconstant`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon but why the wait time is not 9 seconds?  I output a timestamp before execute and after execute the start-sleep, its not 9 second. In computer A become 8s and in computer B become 4s

Comment: Can you output the timestamp before and after **and** output `$Value_x` and show us the results?

Answer (score 0):

The command itself accepts quite a few formats but most should rely on implict type conversion. In your example that should make no difference. If there is a difference there is probably something else going on. It could be worth it to simply run `Get-Help` for `Start-Sleep` or maybe even just the shorthand `Start-Sleep -?`.

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.2) and you will find that `-Seconds` (no reason to use the shorthand) that the command used to expect System.Int32 and with PS 6+ will accept double as a input.

Rather than just printing timestampt to confirm the behavior running [`Measure-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.2) might be more accurate.

```
Measure-Command {Start-Sleep -Seconds $Value_1}
Measure-Command {Start-Sleep -Seconds $Value_2}
```

This should get you something like this:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 9
Milliseconds      : 11
Ticks             : 90118677
TotalDays         : 0.000104304024305556
TotalHours        : 0.00250329658333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.150197795
TotalSeconds      : 9.0118677
TotalMilliseconds : 9011.8677
```